# Problems of VirtualEnv and pip3

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I used VirtualEnv to create a python2 environment without system site packages like this:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 --no-site-packages ENV2.7
```

And I want to install packages  in this environment. 
However, I found that my python code is still trying to look for packages out of this environment.

For example, after activate this env, I used:

```
pip install matplotlib
```

And  in my demo.py, there is

`import matplotlib`

But this raised an error, and can not find this package
However, when I use python in the terminal and enter the interactive python, import matplotlib dose not raise an  error.
Then I started another terminal and tried to install this package out of the environment by pip3:

```
pip3 install matplotlib
```

It turned out that my demo.py just work well.

Any idea?  Many Thanks!

Comment: how are you calling your demo.py? Can you post a mwe of your demo.py? Have you tried prinitng sys.path in your demo.py to see where it looks for packages?

Comment: Also: Have you made sure that you're a using a pip version installed in your environment and not the global one?

Comment: If your virtualenv is 2.7 why on earth did you even *try* to use `pip3`?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your virtualenv pip version may be using pip3 instead of pip2:

Make sure you are using the **correct python version in your project that you mean to**, and using the **same version of pip in your virtualenv**. (Note that you use `pip` above once, then you used `pip3` outside your virtualenv.)

Check your pip version from inside the virtualenv:

```
workon (your env name)
which pip
pip -V
```

Output should look something like:

```
$ which pip
/home/yourname/.virtualenvs/testenv/bin/pip

$ pip -V
pip 9.0.1 from /home/yourname/.virtualenvs/testenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

It should tell you you're using pip inside your virtualenv, and the correct python version.

If that looks correct, install your packages. 
`pip install (whatever)`

Check they are installed with `pip freeze`.

Run your project. :)